# Where did Charting go?

Tags: c#, charts

I've recently moved to Visual Studio 2017 from 2010 where I've been Windows Forms apps with charts.

Where did `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;`

and `using System.Speech.Synthesis;`move to?

Comment: Are you opening an old project? Or creating a new one?

Comment: its still in my .net 4 folder waiting to be added as reference

Comment: Both converting an old project and creating a new one.Is there something newer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use search reference while adding it :

[image]